# I am using PostgreSQL. Can I change the order of columns?

Tags: postgresql, postico

I know that the order is meaningless.

But I want to adjust the order for readability.

**Can not change the order of columns in the postgresql?**

I am using postico for mac.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-create the table with your ordering *du jour*.  However, probably the simplest method is just to query the table with the columns you want:

```
select col3, col1, col4, . . .
from t;
```

You can wrap this in a view so you can use it anytime in the future:

```
create view v_t as
    select col3, col1, col4, . . .
    from t;
```

Comment: MySQL is available.
Is postgresql not possible without regenerating?

Comment: @J.thomas . . . A view is so simple.